# Error Please install pg package manually with AWS Lambda serverless framework

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

recently i had a big headache deploying my serveless application.

I have a lambda function that connect to a Postgresql database. To deploy my application i use serverless framework.

So, after doing my code when testing my code i got the follow error:

**Please install pg package manually**

But, i have installed pg on my package.json.

All the same the error still happened.

So, why do i have this error if the pg is installed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

After hours and hours of searching and changing my code, i decided to refactor it starting from the bottom.

I took off all plugins in serverless, put the raw code and everything worked fine.

With this i had a direction. Some of my serverless plugins was breaking my connection with Postgresql.

So, after testing i got that the break was happening because of [serverless-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-bundl) plugin that i use to optimize my app.

After searching, i got the answer on the package [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-bundle#sequelize).

To use the Sequelize package along with pg, you'll need to ignore it from Webpack and using the dialectModule option. Read more here.

In your serverless.yml:

```
custom:
  bundle:
    ignorePackages:
      - pg-native
```

And in your Lambda code:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    dialectModule: pg
  }
);
```

So, that's it!